# Need space between browser border and OWL Carousel

Tags: html, css

[image: OWL with browser]

How can I add on left and right space (10px) between left and right browser border and OWL carousel?

```
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 10px:
```

has no function. Than I have only left space 10px

Comment: try adding padding to the outer div .owl-carousel

Answer (score 1):

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
}
```

*or*

```
.owl-carousel {
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: That is not the right solution! When I add a bacground color I see that the OWl Carousel goes to the border left and right anymore!

Comment: i added another method . please try again

Comment: don't add background colour to the outer div `.owl-carousel` @SebastianHannes